# Using Scanaerial in JOSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

I am trying to use **[Scanaerial](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/Scanaerial)** in JOSM to locate water sources in my county.  I was able to install all of the required Python modules and ExtTools and load the scanaerial plugin, but now when I run it, it just scans the WMS layer endlessly and never gives me any output, at least for the hour I have let it run on an acre sized area..  All the documentation is on the [OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/Scanaerial) and the files are at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/jonasstein/scanaerial).  I am not sure what I am missing to make this plugin produce some output.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to provide more details about what you mean by "endlessly and never", please?  How long have you left it to run before assuming that it will never complete?

Answer (score 3):

Scanaerial takes lots of time to get results. If the image is not uniform, then it takes more time. The results are also not as good i.e. it does not give boundaries at the right place.

Alternatively, you can digitize large area as smaller pieces and then dissolve the boundaries.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer. Could you give any example times based on particular image sizes or uniformity?

Comment: I know, this is not a good answer as it does not solve the issue. but i don't see possible solutions so posted it as answer. @ChrisW i haven't timed the process, but it takes very long.

Comment: @neogeomat The times don't need to be exact. Something like 'a 4000x4000 pixel image of a 30% urban area took a few hours' - an hour, a few, several, or overnight at least gives *some* idea of what to expect. "Lots" can mean different things to different people. Your answer could be valid, but the key is to give asker an idea of what normal operation is.

Comment: i'm sorry i don't know such details on image resolution and classification so i cannot give a definitive answer. As for user i suggest to digitize, as it is faster and accurate.

Comment: This is all helpful, I have only let the process run at most for an hour without producing any results on a 3mi x 3mi square of imagery.  Has anyone here had success with this tool?